# Creating array of object in another class

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an array of objects from `Person` objects in `Employee` class but I am getting these errors:

> CS0270 Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration (try
> initializing with a 'new' expression)

> CS1519 Invalid token '.' in
> class, struct, or interface member declaration CS1519

> Invalid token
> '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

```
    void Main()
    {
    
    }
    
    public class Person{
        public string Name{ get; set;}
    }
    public class Employee{
        Person[] persons = new Person[3];
        persons[0].Name = "Ali";
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `persons[0].Name = "Ali";` needs to be inside a method

Comment: Thanks Jonesopolis but can I ask you why?

Comment: @Behseini, that is how c# was designed. Contrary to, let's say PHP, you have to organize your code certain way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning value to `persons` array's first element cannot be done this way. You have to do it inside method or constructor. Something like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    Person[] persons = new Person[3];

    //through constructor
    public Employee()
    {
        persons[0].Name = "Ali";
    }

    //method that takes index and name
    public void AddPerson(int index, string name)
    {
        persons[index].Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but the function does not have anything to prevent the user from inputting an index higher than what the array can support.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nino but can you please also let me know what is the logic behind this?

Comment: @JohnOdom that is true, but this is only an example, that shows basic usage.

Comment: @Behseini take a look at documentation that explains [classes and structs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx)

Comment: @John what is the best option to do this then ? I mean if we want also take care of preventing outbond indexing

Comment: @Behseini, check the index and compare with length of array

Comment: Thanks everybody Just one final question? In case of adding a property to the `Employee` class to set/get the new person in Employee. How can I do it?